# multi_index composite_key replace with iterator

Tags: replace, composite-key, multi-index

Is there anyway to loop through an index in a boost::multi_index and perform a replace?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>

using namespace boost::multi_index;
using namespace std;

struct name_record
{

  public:

  name_record(string given_name_,string family_name_,string other_name_)
  {
      given_name=given_name_;
      family_name=family_name_;
      other_name=other_name_;
  }

  string given_name;
  string family_name;
  string other_name;

  string get_name() const { return given_name + " " + family_name + " " + other_name; }

  void setnew(string chg)
  {
      given_name = given_name + chg;
      family_name = family_name + chg;
  }

};

struct NameIndex{};

typedef multi_index_container<
  name_record,
  indexed_by<
    ordered_non_unique<
      tag<NameIndex>,
      composite_key
      <
        name_record,
        BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(name_record,string, name_record::given_name),
        BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(name_record,string, name_record::family_name)
      >
    >
  >
> name_record_set;

typedef boost::multi_index::index<name_record_set,NameIndex>::type::iterator IteratorType;
typedef boost::multi_index::index<name_record_set,NameIndex>::type NameIndexType;

void printContainer(name_record_set & ns)
{
  cout << endl << "PrintContainer" << endl << "-------------" << endl;
  IteratorType it1 = ns.begin();
  IteratorType it2 = ns.end  ();

  while (it1 != it2)
  {
       cout<<it1->get_name()<<endl;
       it1++;
  }
  cout << "--------------" << endl << endl;

}


void modifyContainer(name_record_set & ns)
{
  cout << endl << "ModifyContainer" << endl << "-------------" << endl;
  IteratorType it3;
  IteratorType it4;

  NameIndexType & idx1 = ns.get<NameIndex>();
  IteratorType it1 = idx1.begin();
  IteratorType it2 = idx1.end();

  while (it1 != it2)
  {
        cout<<it1->get_name()<<endl;
        name_record nr = *it1;

        nr.setnew("_CHG");
        bool res = idx1.replace(it1,nr);
        cout << "result is: " << res << endl;
        it1++;
  }
  cout << "--------------" << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
  name_record_set ns;

  ns.insert( name_record("Joe","Smith","ENTRY1")          );
  ns.insert( name_record("Robert","Brown","ENTRY2")       );
  ns.insert( name_record("Robert","Nightingale","ENTRY3") );
  ns.insert( name_record("Marc","Tuxedo","ENTRY4")        );

  printContainer  (ns);
  modifyContainer (ns);
  printContainer  (ns);

  return 0;
}



PrintContainer
-------------
Joe Smith ENTRY1
Marc Tuxedo ENTRY4
Robert Brown ENTRY2
Robert Nightingale ENTRY3
--------------


ModifyContainer
-------------
Joe Smith ENTRY1
result is: 1
Marc Tuxedo ENTRY4
result is: 1
Robert Brown ENTRY2
result is: 1
--------------


PrintContainer
-------------
Joe_CHG Smith_CHG ENTRY1
Marc_CHG Tuxedo_CHG ENTRY4
Robert Nightingale ENTRY3
Robert_CHG Brown_CHG ENTRY2
--------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while (it1 != it2)
{
      cout<<it1->get_name()<<endl;
      name_record nr = *it1;

      nr.setnew("_CHG");
      bool res = idx1.replace(it1,nr);
      cout << "result is: " << res << endl;
      it1++;
}
```

The problem with this code is that, once you've replaced an element `x`, this is automatically reordered to its new position, so that `it1`, which keeps pointing to `x`, "jumps" through the sequence and might skip or revisit elements.

The solution is to add a level of indirection and collect iterators to all the elements before beginning the replacements:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iterator/counting_iterator.hpp>

void modifyContainer(name_record_set & ns)
{
  cout << endl << "ModifyContainer" << endl << "-------------" << endl;

  NameIndexType & idx1 = ns.get<NameIndex>();
  std::vector<IteratorType> v(
    boost::make_counting_iterator(idx1.begin()),
    boost::make_counting_iterator(idx1.end()));
  std::vector<IteratorType>::iterator it1=v.begin(),
                                      it2=v.end();

  while (it1 != it2)
  {
        cout<<(*it1)->get_name()<<endl;
        name_record nr = **it1;

        nr.setnew("_CHG");
        bool res = idx1.replace(*it1,nr);
        cout << "result is: " << res << endl;
        it1++;
  }
  cout << "--------------" << endl << endl;
}
```

In case you didn't use it before, the `make_counting_iterator` bit is just a compact way to populate the vector with iterators to all the elements of `ns`.